# What are the differences between the Golden Ship and the standard ship?

Tags: beat-hazard

During the [Steam Summer Camp sale](http://steamcommunity.com/games/summercamp) in 2011, [Beat Hazard](http://store.steampowered.com/app/49600/) received a new *gear* called **Golden Ship**. (if you didn't unlock it during the summer sale, then you can't unlock it anymore)

So, I've unlocked the golden ship, but what are the differences between it and the normal ship? Are they just cosmetic, or there are gameplay-wise changes too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It's golden, and gives off a power-up like glow that pulses with the music. This helps quite a bit with keeping track of the ship's location, because none of the enemies fall into that color scheme.
- It looks different, apart from the color. It's a bit bigger.
- The turrets are [a bit farther apart](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=23322094&postcount=78).

Answer (score 3):

The differences appear to simply be cosmetic.

Though, arguably, the three spotlights shooting out from the Golden Ship might make it a tad easier to keep track of your screen when you're in the middle of a kaleidoscopic explosion cascade.